# I am looking for a solution to generate a swagger automatically

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, lumen

Stack:

- "laravel/lumen-framework": "^9.1"
- "php": "^8.1"

I heard about the method to write the definitions directly in PhpDocs to generate a swagger.

Can you explain me this solution (the one to write in PhpDocs) or, propose me a better solution please (like some package for example)?

EDIT: Solved by @Aranya Sen:

```
composer require "darkaonline/swagger-lume" -W

$app->withFacades(); add this line before Register Container Bindings section:
    
$app->configure('swagger-lume'); add this line in Register Service Providers section:
    
$app->register(\SwaggerLume\ServiceProvider::class);
```

Write annotations
Generate swagger: `php artisan swagger-lume:generate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package `darkaonline/l5-swagger`. With this, you can add the API documentation in phpdoc, and generate a Swagger documentation using an artisan command `php artisan l5-swagger:generate` provided by this package.

Here are some [examples](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/wiki/Examples) to get a taste of it, and here's the [documentation](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/wiki)

Comment: Thank's you so much! For lumen it's this package : composer require "darkaonline/swagger-lume"

Comment: There is way to generate OA annotation template automatically on Phpstorm?